Implement select in i/o socket receiving messages from other client through server
Ok so I have an assignment and I need to use select to handle receive because it is a blocking function , but I cant get the syntax of select right I read about it but I didn't understand how to implement it.
this is my code
server:
import socket
import select

SERVER_IP = '127.0.0.1'
SERVER_PORT = 33333
SERVER_MSG_LENGTH = 6

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind((SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT))
server_socket.listen(5)

open_client_socket = []
msg_to_send = []


def send_waiting_msg(wlist, sender_socket):
    for message in msg_to_send:
        (client_socket, data) = message
        length = str(len(data)).zfill(6)
        for client_socket in wlist:
            if client_socket != sender_socket:
                msg = length + data
                client_socket.send(msg.encode())
        msg_to_send.remove(message)


def main():
    flag = True
    print("server is running and listening...")
    while flag:
        rlist, wlist, xlist = select.select([server_socket] + open_client_socket, open_client_socket, [])
        for current_socket in rlist:
            if current_socket is server_socket:
                client_socket, address = server_socket.accept()
                open_client_socket.append(client_socket)
                print("connection with {} has been made".format(address))
            else:
                length = current_socket.recv(SERVER_MSG_LENGTH).decode()
                try:
                    data = current_socket.recv(int(length)).decode()
                    print("data")
                    if data == "quit":
                        open_client_socket.remove(current_socket)
                        print("connection has been closed")
                    else:
                        print(data)
                        msg_to_send.append((current_socket, data))
                        send_waiting_msg(wlist, current_socket)
                except Exception as err:
                    print(err)
                    exit(-1)
            if len(open_client_socket) == 0:
                flag = False
    server_socket.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

client socket where I have my problem:
import socket
import msvcrt
import select

SERVER_HOST = '127.0.0.1'
SERVER_PORT = 33333
SERVER_MSG_LENGTH = 6

client_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_sock.connect((SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT))

msg_to_recv = []


def send_msg(msg):
    length = str(len(msg)).zfill(SERVER_MSG_LENGTH)
    msg_send = length + msg
    client_sock.send(msg_send.encode())


def input_message():
    input_string = ""
    flag = True
    while flag:
        if msvcrt.kbhit():
            key = msvcrt.getwche()
            if key == '\r':
                send_msg(input_string)
                flag = False
            else:
                input_string += key
    print(input_string)


def recv_msg():
    length = client_sock.recv(SERVER_MSG_LENGTH).decode()
    msg = client_sock.recv(int(length)).decode()
    print(msg)


def main():
    flag = True
    while flag:
        rlist, wlist, xlist = select.select([client_sock], [client_sock], [])
        if client_sock in rlist:
            recv_msg()
        elif client_sock in wlist:
            input_message()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

I tried to read about this topic but I kind of new to the socket programming so I might misunderstood something but I will really appreciate it if someone could help me.

What exactly is the problem that you encounter?

in the main function of my client I need to wait for all the clients to write something so they can receive the messages and I want the client to be able to receive and send without blocking one another , I know I probably got wrong in the syntax but I don't know how to fix it.

i am interested in the answer using select.  Usually for non-blocking i would use threading or asyncio...
